# using the dput function with lapply

Tags: r, loops, lapply

Is it possible to use dput in a a loop without overwriting the file in each iteration, i.e.,

```
f<-function(x){

dput(x,file="sample.R")

}


lapply(data,function(y) {f(y)})
```

Comment: Maybe you want to look at `dump` and the `append` argument?

Comment: as a matter of style, it's best to use the functional constructs in R in a functional way, ie., with no side effects. This would be a good use case for a `for` construct.

Comment: You can use a global variable, or pass a variable to your function `i` as a counter. `paste0("sample", i, ".R")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do so, but you need to give a connection wich is open in `append` mode.

```
data <- list(1:10, c(1,2,3))
fcon <- file('sample.R', 'a')
lapply(data, dput, file = fcon)
close(fcon)
> readLines('sample.R')
[1] "1:10"       "c(1, 2, 3)"
```

Reason for is clear if you look at `dput` source:

```
> dput
function (x, file = "", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", 
    "showAttributes")) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (nzchar(file)) {
            file <- file(file, "wt")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else file <- stdout()
    ...
}
```

We can see that if `file` argument is character, file connection will be open in `write` mode and existing content will be overridden.

In any case it is simpler to use `dump` for this as suggested in comment, because `dump` has an `append` argument, which determines in what mode the connection will be open.

```
> dump
function (list, file = "dumpdata.R", append = FALSE, control = "all", 
    envir = parent.frame(), evaluate = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) {
    ...
        if (nzchar(file)) {
            file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
            on.exit(close(file), add = TRUE)
        }
        else file <- stdout()
    }
    ...
}
```